# Call methods from set accessor or force the user to do manually

Tags: c#, methods, properties

When a property is updated is it good practice to change other properties based on this or should you force the user to call a method directly? For example:

```
someObject.TodaysTotalSales = 1234.56;
```

Would it be OK to have the set accessor update another value say ThisYearsTotalSales or should you force the end user to do it manually.

```
someObject.TodaysTotalSales = 1234.56;
someObject.UpdateThisYearsTotal();
```

Comment: If the property has a material effect on the status of the object, then it is probably best to update via the "set" method of the property.

Comment: In my opinion is it good practice to use setter for this. But if you need to do tasks which need long time (Database- or Fileoperation for example) you should use methods.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily **opinion-based**

Comment: (I was just typing what is detailed in the follow on comments... fingers too slow :( )

Comment: **Imho**: You should use a method if a setter would have side-effects which are time-consuming. So don't allow to change the property but instead provide a method for this.

Comment: Microsoft says a Property should be lightweight. So i think @Adriano and me are right ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practise is to recalculate the total year consumption only when it is accessed. Otherwise if you update the TodaysTotalSales property very often, you will compute the total year count for nothing.

More generally, when you call a property setter, you don't expect a complex operation. By convention, getters and setters are expected to return almost immediately.

If your algorithm is too complex, in that case you can use a cache value to avoid a recalculation at each call; you invalidate the cache value when one of its prerequisite has changed

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Does he need to know the TotalYearsOfSales even after he updated TodaysSales?

**Yes** -> Provide an additional method to update someObject.UpdateThisYearsTotal(); and at the same time flag that he has not updated YearsTotal while he did update TodaysSales, so you can throw some error at the end of the process if needed

**No** -> Autoupdate other properties of which the values are not needed to prior to updating the TodaysSales

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR: it depends

I assume you have public interface of a class in mind.

If you follow ***OOP Encapsulation*** principle to the limit, then *someObject*'s externally visible state should be consistent with every public access, i.e. you shouldn't need any `public UpdateState` methods. So in this case `someObject.UpdateThisYearsTotal()` is a no-no. What happens internally: be it lazy recalculation, caching, private UpdateAllInternal - would not matter.

But OOP is not an icon/idol - so for performance reasons you may design program flow as you see fit. For example: deferred bulk data processing, game loop, Entity Component System design, ORMs - those systems clearly state in their docs (rarely in code contracts) the way they are supposed to be used.